# Lost editing DNS config in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, dnsmasq, systemd-resolved

### Objective

For personal use, I need to add a custom server running on `127.0.0.1#5354` that resolves queries for `.hyperboria` domains.

### What I've done

There used to be a file called `/etc/resolv.conf` that now says,

```
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
```

So, it seems that since `systemd` is the main responsible for everything, I should look into `systemd-resolved` service/configuration.

I could just edit the NetworkManager WiFi settings in GNOME to add a manual DNS server on my connected network, but that doesn't apply for every network (just the one I've edited). Plus, I couldn't control which domains solve with each server, and I don't know which files are being edited behind the scenes.

On `dnsmasq` I think I could just add this line to its config, `server=/hyperboria/127.0.0.1#5354`, but dnsmasq is not running, and if it would, I've found out that it is wrapped by NetworkManager or something similar and I wouldn't know if I should add a file into `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/` or edit `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`.

Other possible configurations are,

- `/etc/network/interfaces` # not sure how legacy it is these days
- `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base|head|tail`

Anyway, everything seems to rely on `systemd-resolved`. How could achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Try editing `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` file. Also don't forget to restart the appropriate service by `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service`.

Note that:
`/etc/network/interfaces`
`/etc/resolv.conf`
are deprecated now.

Comment: A space-separated list of IPv4 and IPv6 addresses to use as system DNS servers. So 
DNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4